# RewriteRule on special querystring

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

My URLS
the page names example: ?Contact- or ?Product-

some have a longer querystring example: ?Contact-&go=Admin

domain.com/?Contact-&go=Admin

I would like a RewriteRule to use

domain.com/Contact/Admin

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /?$1-&go=$1
```

The first rule is just to exclude requests for existing files.